# Cocos2d & Box2d dynamic lighting and shadows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, lighting

I'm looking to start building an iPhone app and I was wondering if it was possible to create dynamic lighting/shadows using the Cocos2d/Box2D combo? I have worked with these before and would like to stay with them. I would like the lighting to update dynamically as the player moves around.

An example of the desired effect is:

[image: Genome 2D]

Found at http://blog.flash-core.com/?p=135

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cocos3D (an extension to cocos2D) may have what you need. http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/

Comment: That looks like the perfect solution for me, have you had any experience with this extension?

Comment: I've only thrown together a couple of basic things in it, it all seems to work as advertised and is all very familiar if you're used to cocos2d.